# Combining Geological Grids and extruding between them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, geology

I have a situation where I have 3 Geological grids, each showing a different horizon + the Seabed Grid.

I need to extrude between these grids in order to make the 3D polygon for the geological unit which is between these horizons. The problem occurs however when (due to Shallow gas or lower geological units protruding upwards) there are gaps in my grid; sometimes to the extent that one of the horizons only covers a small segment of the sea bed area at the surface. The solution therefore (I think) is to combine say, H3 + H2 for example, and H2 +1, and then: Extrude between [(H3+H2) (where H2 fills in the gaps of H3)] and [(H2 +H1)(Where H2 Fills in the Gaps of H1)].

The Situation becomes very complicated when some of H3 actually rises to the Seabed and the Seabed fills in some gaps in H3. A very complex series of combinations of grids is therefore needed involving probably H3, H2, H1 and the Seabed.

The only way I have found to do this is in Global Mapper, but version I have does not have the combine grids tool, unlike the expensive newest version. The software I Have access to include Arc GIS 10.2 and freeware such as Map window, QGIS, GRASS etc. The solution may involve raster calculator conditional function, however I have no experience in how to accomplish this task using this.

Answer (score 7):

It is very complicated and that's why there are specialized applications as [gOcad](http://www.gocad.org/w4/), for example.

I use [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) because I can build volumes (3D voxels) from surfaces/grids ([Help with 3D](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D)), even if the surfaces are not "perfect":

[image]

[image]

Application with two layers from [El modelado geólogico para un geológo sin recursos o entusiasta: GRASS GIS (y Paraview)](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/322-el-modelado-geologico-para-un-geologo-sin-recursos-o-entusiasta-grass-gis-y-paraview) (in Spanish: Geological modeling for a geologist without resources or enthusiast: GRASS GIS (and Paraview))

Voxel 3D (volumes) from 2 geological layers

[image]

Applications with boreholes:

[image]
[image]

Grass GIS with [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) (from [GRASS GIS - users: Searching Docs about 3D geological modelisation](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Searching-Docs-about-3D-geological-modelisation-td3904580.html))

[image]

But the more impressive work is the one of Maciej Tomaszczyk in [Opengeology.pl](http://opengeology.pl/index.html), in Polish.

[image]

[image]

or the publications of:

- Masumoto, S. , Raghavan V., Nemoto, T., Shiono K.,(2002), [Construction and Visualization of Three Dimensional Geologic Model Using GRASS GIS](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/conferences/GRASS2002/proceedings/proceedings/pdfs/Masumoto_Shinji.pdf). In M. Ciolli and P. Zatelli, editors, Open Source Free Software GIS - GRASS users conference 2002
- Yonezawa , G., Nemoto T., Masumoto S., and Shiono K., (2002) [3-D Geologic Modeling and Visualization of Faulted Structures](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/conferences/GRASS2002/proceedings/proceedings/pdfs/Yonezawa_Go.pdf). In M. Ciolli and P. Zatelli, editors, Open Source Free Software GIS - GRASS users conference 2002 ->
- Kajiyama , A., Ikawa, N., Masumoto S., Shiono K., Raghavan V., (2004), [Three-dimensional Geological Modeling  by FOSS GRASS GIS –Using Some Field Survey Data](http://www.gisdevelopment.net/proceedings/fossgrass/papers/Three-dimensional%20Geological%20Modeling.pdf) , Proceedings of the FOSS/GRASS Users Conference - Bangkok, Thailand, 12-14 September 2004
- Masumoto, S., Nonogaki,S., Nemoto, T, Shiono, K.,Raghavan,(2006), [Development of Visualization Tool for Geologic Information on GRASS GIS](http://wgrass.media.osaka-cu.ac.jp/gisideas06/viewpaper.php?id=170), GeoInformatics for Spatial-Infrastructure Development in Earth and Allied Sciences (GIS-IDEAS) 2006, Vietnam

From the first paper (fig 9):

[image]
[image]

From the second paper (fig 5)

[image]